# Level Modeling Workflows in Maya for Unity

Tags: unity, models, level-design, maya

I'm wondering what the standard workflow for modeling static levels for Unity (or for that matter, other High-Level engines) is? My somewhat limited knowledge tells me that the best process is modeling the entire static level in Maya, texturing, then baking AO and some static lighting into the scene, then importing the single level asset into unity to add dynamic objects.

Is there another way that I should be doing this that is more efficient in a performance sense or from a workflow point of view?

I know the question is somewhat open ended, but generally i'm asking what the standard workflow for level modeling is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an real modeling guy and my level design experience is also limited but i honestly  give you some guidelines

- Do model each model and instatiate them in your level with the Unity editor

This does have the advantage that you can use your statics for other elvels or that you can alter your level quickly without going into maya and exporting it again into unity.

You can also bake lighting with the unity editor (im not sure if AO works too).

The unity Level editor is just awesome work, so use it.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but for rooms, should i be modelling the entire room in Maya? or build it out of segments in unity? Should i at least have a level proxy built in maya?

Comment: it is better to build a room with segments, but a proxy is a good idea

Comment: That was good enough to get me on the right track, I can't Upvote yet so i'll accept the answer. Thanks!